# Can "partial" surprise happen? Would it be an acceptable rule?

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules, surprise

I'm thinking the "surprise round" rule (PHB page 189) just isn't fair.
It says :

> If you're surprised, you can't move or take an action on
> your first turn of the combat, and you can't take a reaction
> until that turn ends. A member of a group can be surprised
> even if the other members aren't

Say there's a 2 vs 2 encounter (teams PC and Creatures (Cs)), then PC1 could notice the 2 Cs and PC2 just one of them. Also for the sake of discussion PC1 is mute for whatever reason, so he can't quickly communicate with PC2 and he also plays last according to iniciative order. Then PC2 loosing an entire round seems unfair to me, because he could perfectly be taking actions against the C he found. Also if PC2 gets attacked by the Cs it would be doubly unfair, even if one has advantage and the other don't, it's 2 actions against none.
So I figured you could ask PC2 to just turn around when it isn't his turn during the surprise round, so as not to reveal the concealed C position to him and then, when he plays his turn remove the hidden C and let PC2 play as always...or if he gets attacked by hidden C before his turn he now sees it.
How would combat change, if I made this house rule, are there any problems I don't see?

Comment: Why surprise round rule are you referring to? 5e doesn’t have surprise rounds.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov , YES I KNOW it's not explicitly called that way, but the PH clearly says that players surprised don't get to play the first turn nor have reactions, so virtually they're useless during the entire first round or nearly as...also from  the PC point of view he seemingly could be attacking or moving towards seen threats regardless not noticing others...

Comment: Welcome to RPG SE! Perhaps add the rule quote for "surprised", or at least link to basic rules, or page number for PHB, if you are asking about surprise. At least add a few paragraph breaks. Also "What do you think?" is kind of a no-no question here. You might want to ask something lile "How would combat change, if I made this house rule, are there any problems I don't see?" Or something else specific.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir OK ok i'll rephrase the question and add the quote....i assumed ANYONE answering here would at least know the basic rules, so i omitted the quotation

Comment: I'm not really understanding what the point of having them turn around is, when it's not their turn they can't do anything regardless of whether they can see the map. When their turn happens, they get to turn and see the map anyway? Also, they can still hear the DM (and it will do nothing at all if you're not playing on a map)

Comment: @DanB What i propose isn't similar to existing rules, I'm stating that the surprised player CAN play his first turn when the PHB clearly says he can't. And then I say HOW shall he play it

Comment: @Ethan1987 I initially close voted because it was not at all clear to me what you were proposing or what rules you were changing (I’m still not sure). See this meta discussion for more details about question closure: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/why-was-my-question-closed-as-too-broad-unclear-or-opinion-based

Comment: Welcome to the community, sorry your comment got downvoted so badly for a common mistake. If you had asked "what am I missing here" you may have been better received and been informed that PC2 would be able to act and wouldn't be "surprised". However, this is rather a basic mistake that may not be seen as something Stack Exchange has to deal with.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry for a part of the community to be prone to just nearly hate begginers asking questions or just for how those are written, instead of willing to comprehend and help as it's supposed to, like DanB did when he answered with his +6 post. After all, there was something interesting he could see, for example.

Answer (score 8):

The rules say:

> Any character or monster that doesn’t notice a threat is surprised at the start of the encounter.

That means they are surprised if they do not notice *any* threat.

In the scenario you describe, PC2 has noticed a threat and therefore is not surprised.

---

You've asked how to handle the case where PC2 is not aware of a combatant. The thing you describe would work, but might be annoying to the player who is asked to leave the table. What I do instead is I don't put the monster on the board until its position is revealed. So I might tell PC1 "you notice there's another monster, in the bushes over there. I'll put it on the map if it attacks or if you point out its position on your turn."

I might just not say anything until PC1's turn comes up, and then I'd put the monster on the board and say "you also see this one hiding in the bushes".

Either of these approaches has worked for me.

Comment: Oh, you're right about the PHB rules, wich i missunderstood a bit... but thanks for interpreting the real issue (wich you adress on your second part). Very helpful, thank you for your time.